# Some issues with a 'scroll to top button'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I have this 'scroll to top button' that pops up after the user has scrolled down 300px. Everything works fine so far. What I'm trying to do now, is to make this button pop up at a specific element.

**Here is the jQuery**:

```
// hide #back-top first
$("#back-top").hide();

// fade in #back-top
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('#back-top').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#back-top').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    // scroll body to 0px on click
    $('#back-top a').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Ok, I then changed this line

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
```

to

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > '.show-button-here') {
```

but it didn't work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here is a fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/v70L4buk/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the position of the element from the top of the page and then subtract how far from the top you want that element to get before showing the up arrow. In this case, I am showing the arrow when a link I created in the page gets to 300px from the top. Or you can remove the number and when that element gets to the top of the viewport the function will kick in.

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('.show').offset().top - 300) {
```

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/gvpLe06c/1/

Comment: Oh, I guess my question wasn't precise enough. I would like to have the button appear when you scroll down to a specific div, for example the one I used in my fiddle `.show-button-here`. What I don't want is that it shows up based on pixels height, like you did it in your example. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Without a jQuery plugin (https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery) or extensive coding, this is the simplest method. Change '.show' to the element you wish and change the '300' to how far you want it to be from the top before the arrow shows up. I added the '.show' link just for testing purposes. It can be any element.